# Sending a file from windows via a USB NFC device to NFC enabled phone

Tags: windows, nfc

I would like to create a windows app that sends a URL or a small file via NFC (preferably) From windows to android and from windows to ios. Has anyone any info or code examples in C# (or other language) in windows that demonstrates how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did look at something related, I investigated Sending small files from Android to Android via NFC but decided against it.

This is because in Android as of Android 10 that "Android Beam" has been deprecated this means that Android's ability to receive files has been removed. From experience on early version of Android I can see why they removed it as it was too reliable.

**Update:**
Additional info Android did use LLCP sockets to do peer to peer NFC transfer. the source code for how Android did one end of this is available at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/nfc/ndefpush/NdefPushServer.java

I'm not sure if there was anything similar in iOS.

This leaves you the option of writing code on Windows that does Host Card Emulation(HCE) to emulate a card that carries a Standard NDEF message which can contain things like URL's or data of certain mime types.

**Update:**
I can say for Android that if the NDEF message contains a URL in the right form that the OS will Launch a Browser to load that URL automatically (If you have multiple Web browsers install it might ask the user which Web browser to use to do this). For iOS I don't know but expect the same behaviur

While I believe that HCE is possible to emulate an card with NDEF message on it I've not seen any code to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Andrew, I think this may be the path I will have to go down with  HCE - URL to a hosted file "somewhere" - do you know if default handlers on the phone end will launch the app (after asking permission) on ios and android. I had read that there is a P2P mode with NFC, allowing file transfer @ around 400kbits - but I have struggled to find ANY coding examples for this mode. It is so "closed loop" due to the tech being primarily used in financial transaction systems.

Comment: Updated the answer, Android will launch a web browser if a Card (Or emulated card) has a URL in the right NDEF type of message. The P2P mode is what Android Beam used and it uses LLCP sockets. But that has been removed and they say use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct to send files instead.